# Get key pressed from other application C#

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, postmessage, user32

I would like to get the key pressed by user on other application. For example, in notepad, not the program itself. Here is my coding that using `PostMessage` method to continuously send key to notepad but however, I wish to stop it when some key is pressed.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(
    string ClassName,
    string WindowName);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
    IntPtr Parent,
    IntPtr Child,
    string lpszClass,
    string lpszWindows);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 PostMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    int Msg,
    int wParam,
    int lParam);

private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
    t.Start();
}

Boolean ControlKeyDown = true;

public void Test()
{
    // retrieve Notepad main window handle
    IntPtr Notepad = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");

    if (!Notepad.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        // retrieve Edit window handle of Notepad
        IntPtr Checking = FindWindowEx(Notepad, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);

        if (!Checking.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {

            while (ControlKeyDown)
            {                        
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                PostMessage(Checking, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.A, 0);                                                             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hence, my idea is set the `ControlKeyDown` to `false` when user pressed `X` key in notepad. After research through internet, I found out this code and edited:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs kea)
{
    if (kea.KeyCode == Keys.X)
    ControlKeyDown = false;
}
```

Yes, by this, it definitely will stop the looping but this is not I want as it will stop the loop when user presses `X` key on the program but not in notepad. This is because the `KeyEventArgs` is `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` and not Notepad.

Need help :(

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for keyboard hooking. [See this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx), it is c++ but you appear to be agile in p/invoke so you probably get how to port it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowsHookEx) function in the user32.dll.

I also user the [gma.UserActivity](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx?msg=3110732) library to do it in a project.